# Source Not Found when starting activity

Tags: android

When i try to redirect to next activity... 
I am getting an error message stating as Source Not Found... 
I am new to android development.

The following code is shows the activity which i need to redirect...

```
public class Disclaimer extends Activity {

Bundle bunUserInfo = null;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   
        setContentView(R.layout.disclaimer);
```

//Anyone plz help me.

Comment: have you defined this activity in your manifest?

Comment: then how are you trying to launch the new activity? paste your code for that

Comment: Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), Disclaimer.class);
              goToNextActivity.putExtras(bunUserInfo);
              startActivityForResult(goToNextActivity, 0);

Comment: just a guess, instead of using view.getContext(), try keyword 'this'

Comment: if still doesnt work then paste a part of your manifest too

Answer (score 1):

Add The Disclaimer to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".Disclaimer"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```